# AWS Amplify/amplify-js forgotPassword() returns no error with invalid userName

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I'm implementing authentication components with aws-amplify (Vue/TypeScript).
Using forgotPassword(userName: string), I'm trying to send a verification code to the target email address.
https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/authclass.html#forgotpassword

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'
...
await Auth.forgotPassword(emailAddress)
```

[image]

However, with an invalid email address that is not one of the Cognito users, it returns this success message.

```
{"CodeDeliveryDetails":{"AttributeName":"email","DeliveryMedium":"EMAIL","Destination":"****@d***.com"}}
```

What I want is this.

```
{"__type":"UserNotFoundException","message":"Username/client id combination not found."}
```

I doubt mis-configuration on AWS Cognito, but cannot figure out what to change..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visit **Your User Pools**

Go to **App  Client** in left navigation Bar.

Then scroll down to **Security configuration**.

Do select **Legacy** under "Prevent User Existence Errors"

Note:- Default option is **Enabled(Recommended)**. This default option is actual root cause.

[image]
[image]

Now when you enter **wrong username** [in my case email-id], It will throw the exception.

[image]

[image]

If you entered correct **username** [in my case email-id], Then it **send verification code**.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set *Prevent User Existence Errors* to legacy in app client setting. By doing this you will get the error if email does not exist in user pool.

Answer (score 0):

[AWS Cognito: Managing error responses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pool-managing-errors.html)

> When a user isn't found, is disabled, or doesn't have a mechanism to recover their password, Amazon Cognito returns CodeDeliveryDetails with a simulated delivery medium for a user. The simulated delivery medium is determined by the input user name format and verification settings of the user pool.

I need to check the Cognito configuration.

Comment: Cannot figure out where I can control the password reset permission. Is there any?